# What Would You Call Someone Willing to Turn On Anyone, And Though They'll Help You- They Could Be Helping Your Enemy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm talking about neutral people, who can be villains and heroes. For example, they'll help you carry out a robbery but wouldn't mind helping the person being robbed by telling you they've got it out for you, and telling them that you've got it out for them.
I hope this makes sense, and if it doesn't here's a scenario:

Bob sells information. He will sell Jeff information from Tom. 
But he decides to get profit from Jeff and turn this around on to Tom.

What I'm saying is, they can't be trusted and are egotistical masterminds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a [*double-dealer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-dealer) is what you're looking for. If that's not to your liking, you can always consult a thesaurus. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Curious.Cake Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Duplicitous**

Adjectival form of [duplicity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duplicity):

> 1
> : contradictory doubleness of thought, speech, or action, 
> especially : the belying of one's true intentions by deceptive words or action

**Perfidious**
Adjectival form at [perfidy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfidy):

> 1
> : the quality or state of being faithless or disloyal, treachery 
> 2
> : an act or an instance of disloyalty

Comment: These definitions work wonderfully! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If he’s motivated by personal gain (e.g., money),
he could be a ***mercenary***. 
Otherwise, he could be a ***sociopath***.